# How to make website scroll with the background not moving and toolbar automatically minimize?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a JS for these features or how actually does it works? (Please check out the sites below)

As the user scrolls down the top toolbar minimizes and remains at the top. Also the pictures seems not to move with the scroll...

Thanks!

http://getflywheel.com/

http://www.google.com/nexus/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example you have to set the `position:fixed` attribute on css for your background. An eventhandler must be check if the user had reached the bottom to display the toolbar on top of the page.

In the second example there is no fixed background but a [**parallanxed** background here is a good example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/).

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` for toolbar.
In first example also event handler for JS onscroll event, where check if user scrolled
enough to show toolbar